# iPhone 4.0 build on iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, app-store-connect

I am currently developing a app with deployment target as iPhone 3.1 and base SDK as 4.0. I am not designing my app specially for iPad, many folks say that this will work on iPad as well.

So please let me know whether this is correct ?
if yes, what should be specified @ iTunes connect for iPad and iPhone? should we specify anything special there for iPad ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, this'll work. Not sure what you mean though by specifying something special for iPad.
All you need to do when submitting is check the checkbox that says you've tested on iPad.

To test it yourself, use the Simulator 3.2 (this will test it on iPad simulator).
Good luck.

Comment: You can't rely only on the Simulator. The only way to make sure the application will run correctly on the iPad is to actually test on the device. I wouldn't check the checkbox without testing on an actual iPad.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this will work, as AlvinfromDiaspar has said. I'm doing the exact same thing and here are my settings.

Be sure to "Edit Active Target" instead of "Edit Project Settings", as this makes a major impact on the final binary.

Also, be sure to set the "Targeted Device Family" to "iPhone" and not "iPhone/iPad" *if* you want to keep the application running as an iPhone app (with the 1x/2x button on the iPad).